# csv file import into database, php

Tags: php

I am trying to code a page that allows importing a csv file into the database. I am having issues getting the import to work. It has worked on occasion but for no apparent reason it stops working. I know the script is connecting to the db as I add a manual entry into the db and truncate clears the database ok but does not import the data. I have the db table with columns setup to reflect each column in the csv. Can anyone please assist in troubleshooting this issue. Here is my code.

**db-config.php**

```
<?php
    define('_DB_HOST_NAME','localhost');
    define('_DB_USER_NAME','root');
    define('_DB_PASSWORD','');
    define('_DB_DATABASE_NAME','stock_planner');

    $dbConnection = mysqli_connect(_DB_HOST_NAME,_DB_USER_NAME,_DB_PASSWORD,_DB_DATABASE_NAME);

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        include_once 'db-config.php';
        if (!$dbConnection)
        {
          print "<h1>Unable to connect to the database, contact your administrator!</h1>";
        }
        else
        {
        $truncate = "TRUNCATE TABLE stock_sales_report";
        $file = $_FILES['csv_stock']['name'];
        $import = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
                INTO TABLE stock_sales_report
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
                IGNORE 1 LINES;";
        mysqli_query($dbConnection,$truncate);
        mysqli_query($dbConnection,$import);
        print "<h1>successfully imported.</h1>";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Planner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Upload CSV: <input type='file' name='csv_stock' /> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='import' />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get errors?

Comment: It may be something to do with the temporary nature of `$_FILES`: http://www.phpforkids.com/php/php-forms-file-uploads.php. Run these other checks apart from `isset` for uploads? http://www.phpforkids.com/php/php-forms-file-uploads.php

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be connecting with an account that has FILE permissions on the database. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) FILE privileges are granted at the server level, not just to a specific database.

Second, you'll need to send the full path of the file to the command if it's not uploaded to the same directory as the executing script.

Comment: I had a --secure-file-priv issue which would not accept my file from an unauthorised folder location which I disabled.
Then my import stopped on INT columns where the csv value was blank, I modified the sql query to change blank values to 0 on INT columns.
The problem I've hit now is the import is stuck on non utf8 characters showing up in the CSV, I can get around this by setting the database to Collation to Latin1 and it imports OK, but is this good practice? I guess I need a way of stripping these hex characters from the CSV before importing. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: UTF-8 should cover all your character sets. You may have a mismatch between the database collation and your connection.